# Formatting a string for time format when input is empty

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

When I get a string such as `"1245PM"` the mask below formats it for me correctly in a form like `"12:45 PM"`
The problem is when my input string is **empty** as `""` then it will show it is `": "` which is silly.
How should I improve my mask such that if input string is empty it also outputs an empty string?

```
<Setter Property="MaskType" Value="Standard" />
<Setter Property="Mask" Value="##:## ll"></Setter>
<Setter Property="Placeholder" Value=" " />
```

Comment: What type is this `Mask` property on? Is this WPF or Silverlight, or does it really apply to both? Why not use a `DateTime` and a format string?

Comment: @TimS. It is a string. I have also written some converter logic for it to handle some situations. It is for Silverlight.

Comment: If it's Null, could do `TargetNullValue=''` If it's not could use `FallbackValue=''`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`DateTime` `Mask` `t`](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radmaskedtextbox-features-date-time-mask.html):

```
<Setter Property="MaskType" Value="DateTime" />
<Setter Property="Mask" Value="t" />
```